# How to stop a function in a while loop in python

Tags: python, function, loops, conditional-statements, exit

Basically I want to stop a function but not by terminating the script.

```
While True:
  do function A()
  do function B()
  if ( condition ):
    function B.stop()
```

What I mean is when the condition is met, the while loop still runs but in the next iteration of the while loop, it only does function A, no longer does it do function B. I wonder if we can archive this in python?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what Function B and A are... can you give more details on these functions.

Comment: `if not condition: do function B()` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a flag within the loop

```
flag = True

while True:
  if flag:
    do function B()

  if condition:
    flag = false
```

Comment: depends on the functions of A or B this may or may not work as intended hence we should ask OP for clarification...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a while loop, you can do Ctrl C.

```
while True:
    print("Hello")
```

To stop it, do ctrl - c

```
Ctrl C
```

This is what you will get:

```
   ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
        File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
             input()
        KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).